# Java regex trying to split string up

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Hi I am trying to split this string up (its quite long):

```
Library Catalogue Log off | Borrower record | Course Reading | Collections | A-Z E-Journal list | ILL Request | Help   Browse | Search | Results List | Previous Searches | My e-Shelf | Self-Issue | Feedback       Selected records:  View Selected  |  Save/Mail  |  Create Subset  |  Add to My e-Shelf  |        Whole set:  Select All  |  Deselect  |  Rank  |  Refine  |  Filter   Records 1 - 15 of 101005 (maximum display and sort is 2500 records)         1 Drower, E. S. (Ethel Stefana), Lady, b. 1879. Lady E.S. Drower’s scholarly correspondence : an intrepid English autodidact in Iraq / edited by 2012. BK Book University Library( 1/ 0) 2 Kowalski, Robin M. Cyberbullying : bullying in the digital age / Robin M. Kowalski, Susan P. Limber, Patricia W. Ag 2012. BK Book University Library( 1/ 0) ...  15 Ambrose, Gavin. Approach and language [electronic resource] / Gavin Ambrose, Nigel Aono-Billson. 2011. BK Book
```

So that I either get back:

```
1 Drower, E. S. (Ethel Stefana), Lady, b. 1879. Lady E.S. Drower’s scholarly correspondence : an intrepid English autodidact in Iraq / edited by 2012. BK Book University Library( 1/ 0)

// Or

1 Drower, E. S. (Ethel Stefana), Lady, b. 1879. Lady E.S. Drower’s scholarly correspondence : an intrepid English autodidact in Iraq
```

This is just an example and the 1 Drower, E. S. ... will not be static. While the input will be different every time (the detail between 1 and 2) the general layout of the string will always be the same.

I have:

```
String top = ".*         (.*)";
String bottom = "\( \d/ \d\)\W*";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(top); //+bottom
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(td); //td is the input String
String items = matcher.group();
System.out.println(items);
```

When I run it with `top`, it is meant to remove all of the headers but all I get back is `No match found`. `bottom` is my attempt to split the rest of the string.

I can post all of the input up to number 15 if it is needed. What I need is to split up the input string so that I can work with each individual of the 15 results.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This will provide both inputs for you. It is what you wanted?

```
String text = "Library Catalogue Log off ..."; \\truncated text

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((1 Drower.+Iraq).+0\\)).+2 Kowalski");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

[Compile and run code here.](http://ideone.com/D9vRl)

Comment: In a way yes it is. But the thing is that the input is not static and the will change dependent on the search results. Sorry, I should have mentioned that. However, The layout of the input string will not change. Number 1 is just the first search result and it will go up to 15 results. I can post all of the input up to number 15 if it is needed.

Comment: So you need to split all search results as I understand?

Comment: Yes that is correct. For example: [1 Drower, E. S. ..] should be one String and [2 Kowalski, Robin M. ..] up to [15 Ambrose, Gavin. ..]  should be the next string. This input changes depending on the results from the search. But the Layout of the input string will always be the same. So 1, 2, 3 .. 15. Will always be there unless there are less then 15 results

Answer (score 0):

First off you need to separate the headers from the result data. Assuming that each time there will be that block of 9 whitespaces you can use this: `.*\s{9}(.*)`

Next you need to parse the data into rows, this is more difficult because you have no row delimiters. The best you can do is assume that rows are delimited by: a space then one or more digits then another space.

`((?<=(?:^|\s))\d+\s.*?(?=(?:$|\s\d+\s)))`

If you're planning to try to parse the records into fields then don't bother unless you can change the delimiters!

A little explanation of what each bit does:

`(?<=(?:^|\s))` **Look behind**: Make sure the characters preceding the group is either the start of the string (1st record), or a space (all other records).

`\d+\s.*?` **Capture group**: One or more digits followed by a space, then followed by text. This is the only part of the expression that shows up in the output because of the use of non-capturing groups `?:` in the assertions.

`(?=(?:$|\s\d+\s))` **Look ahead**: Make sure the characters following the group are either the end of string marker `$` or a space followed by 1+ digits, followed by a space (indicating the next record).

This method is works with the fields you provided, but it will break if you have a record that contains the custom delimiter e.g. a book called "My 10 favourite things". There other ways of parsing records that are a little safer, but if that's what you want to do then it's beyond the expectations of regex...